# Get information about the audit state of software (for OSS)?

Tags: audit, opensource

How does one go about to determine how well audited/checked a software is?
To make this a much more specific question I am interested in ways to ascertain (mailing lists, rankings etc.) that a software **(obviously a OSS)** is to some [measurement?] degree audited?